# Help me untangle these wires!

Tags: code-golf, string

## My wires are all tangled!

Isn't it annoying when wires get all tangled up? Well, that just happened to me, so I'd like to to help me untangle them! For your convenience, I've disconnected them all from the device, but they're all still connected to the outlet. Your challenge is to figure out how to untangle them!

## Input

The input will consist of spaces, pipes, and Xs (both cases). The input will look something like this:

```
| | | |
 X  | |
| |  x 
|  X  |
| | | |
```

A capital X means that the left wire crosses over the right wire, and a lowercase x means the opposite. The first and last lines will always be `| | | |...`. You may take the input as a comma separated string, an array of strings, etc. The format is not strict, as long as it makes sense and doesn't contain any extra information.

## Output

For this challenge, not only do I need to know how long I will take, I need to know exactly what to do. So, output a list of integer pairs with the character R or L, case insensitive, representing which two wires to untangle and which way (R means right over left, and vice versa for L). You need to tell me which way to uncross them; I can't figure that out myself. Output is pretty flexible too, as long as you output all of the integer pairs + character in the correct order and you don't output any extra nonsense text (brackets, commas, etc. are fine). The wires can be zero or one indexed, but the index must start from the left. Note that you must untangle from the bottom, not the top. Output style must be consistent, and please specify how you are outputting if it is not obvious. The case of the character doesn't have be consistent, if that helps at all.

## Sample Output

For the example input above, the output would be something like:

```
2 3 R
3 4 L
1 2 R
```

The output format here is a newline separated list of space separated values. This is 1-indexed.

## Further specifications

It is valid to have X and x stacked vertically over each other in either order. Since I'm lazy, I don't want to switch wires around unnecessarily, so don't output anything for these cases; if I find that, I'll just pull the wires gently to get them straight.

It is also valid to have multiple X and x stacked vertically, and as long as neither wire is involved in other crossings, I don't want any extra moves (because I'm lazy). Thus, if the characters `X X x X x x` show up in a column without any other crossings, the output should still be blank!

In case this isn't clear, R eliminates X and L eliminates x.

There could be two wire crossings in the same row, in which case the order of these two swaps does not matter. You will never get something like `|  X X  |` (this does not make sense because it implies that the middle wire is being crossed over the wires on both its left and its right).

There aren't always crossings...

The input could be a single pipe. However, the input will never be blank.

Shortest valid solution wins on December 20th!

## More Examples

As I promised:

#### Example 1

**Input**

```
| | | | | |
| |  X   x 
 X  |  x  |
|  x  |  X 
 X   X  | |
| | | | | |
```

**Output**

```
1 2 R
3 4 R
2 3 L
5 6 R
1 2 R
4 5 L
3 4 R
5 6 L
```

#### Example 2

**Input**

```
| | |
 X  |
|  x 
| | |
|  X 
|  x 
| | |
```

**Output**

```
2 3 L
1 2 R
```

#### Example 3

**Input**

```
|
```

**Output** is blank. Yes, you have to deal with this case.

#### Example 4

**Input**

```
| |
 X 
 x 
 X 
 x 
 X 
 x 
 X 
 x 
 X 
 x 
| |
```

**Output** is blank. Just for fun :).

#### Example 5

**Input**

```
| |
 X 
 X 
 x 
 X 
 x 
 x 
| |
```

**Output** is still blank...

Comment: Is it possible to have two pairs of wires entangled in the same row?

Comment: @JamesHolderness Yes, it is. In this case, the order does not matter. I will clarify that in the question. Thanks!

Comment: @JamesHolderness Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Befunge, 173 bytes

Input is read from stdin in the exact format given in the challenge description, although it's crucial that every line be the correct length and the final line must include a newline (i.e. not just EOF at the end of that line).

```
$1>>05p~$~:55+-#v_
$_^#`"N":+1g50$<>:2+3%1-05g6g+0v>!#:v#
vg50-1*2p51:-1_^#:<*2!!-*84p6g5<
 +#,.#$"R"\#\-#+5<^g51$_:0`6*\25g\v@_:#!.#:1#,
>+::25p6g\48*\6p48 *-:!^!:--1*2`0:<
```

[Try it online!](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=JDE-PjA1cH4kfjo1NSstI3ZfCiRfXiNgIk4iOisxZzUwJDw-OjIrMyUxLTA1ZzZnKzB2PiEjOnYjCnZnNTAtMSoycDUxOi0xX14jOjwqMiEhLSo4NHA2ZzU8CiArIywuIyQiUiJcI1wtIys1PF5nNTEkXzowYDYqXDI1Z1x2QF86IyEuIzoxIywKPis6OjI1cDZnXDQ4Klw2cDQ4ICotOiFeITotLTEqMmAwOjw&input=fCB8IHwKIFggIHwKfCAgeCAKfCB8IHwKfCAgWCAKfCAgeCAKfCB8IHwK)

The basic idea for this solution is that we have an "array" keeping track of the twist counts for each wire. So every time we encounter a twist in one direction we increment the count for the associated wire, while a twist in the other direction will decrement the count.

At the same time as we process the twist for a particular wire, we also look at the twist count for the wires to the left and right of it. If either of them are non-zero, we need to "flush" those twists onto the stack, since it will no longer be possible for them to be unravelled by later twists in the opposite direction.

After the last line of input, the input stream returns EOF repeatedly, and these EOF characters are interpreted as twists in every wire, at least for the purposes of flushing. This forces the program to flush any outstanding counts in the array, but it will not generate any new twist counts.

Once we've finished processing the input, all the commands for untangling the wires will now be on the stack. This means we can simply pop them off in reverse order to output the instructions needed to untangle the wires from the bottom up.

Comment: This appears to work perfectly. Good job!

Comment: This is the winning answer. Good job! Also, thanks for checking the other answers for me! :)

Comment: @AlexL. Thanks. This is my first winning answer on the site. Didn't think that would ever be possible with Befunge. :)

Comment: No problem. Congrats on the win! I'm rather surprised as well as to how short you made a Befunge answer. :)

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth - <s>26</s> 25 bytes

Very straightforward, maybe I can golf the filtering.

```
fhhT_m+hB/xrdZ\x2@"RL"}\x
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=fhhT_m%2BhB%2FxrdZ%5Cx2%40%22RL%22%7D%5Cx&input=%5B%27%7C+%7C+%7C+%7C%27%2C+%27+X++%7C+%7C%27%2C+%27%7C+%7C++x+%27%2C+%27%7C++X++%7C%27%2C+%27%7C+%7C+%7C+%7C%27%5D&debug=0).

Comment: Good attempt. Unfortunately, the character being output is not correct; it seems to be R every time. Good try though; the numbers are coming out correctly!

Comment: @AlexL. I'm stupid, I had flipped the args to `in`, fixed, and it saved me a byte too

Comment: I see. Nice answer! Have an upvote. :)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this doesn't appear to handle the case where you have X and x stacked vertically. It tells you to swap the wires back and forth unnecessarily.

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), 178 bytes

```
f=([t,...a],r=[])=>a[0]?t.replace(/x/gi,(c,i)=>(c=c<'x'?'R':'L',i=++i/2,r.reduce((f,[j,,d],n)=>f||i<j+2&&j<i+2&&(j-i|c==d||r.splice(n,1)&&2),0)<2?r=[[i,i+1,c],...r]:r))&&f(a,r):r
```

Takes input as an array of strings representing lines and returns an array of arrays of values e.g. `[[2, 3, "R"], [3, 4, "L"], [1, 2, "R"]]`. The reverse ordering helps with the eliminations.

Comment: Where are you getting `s` from? I'm running it on repl.it and it's telling me that there's a `ReferenceError: s is not defined`.

Comment: @AlexL. Oops, I accidentally pasted in the previous version of my code, which I hadn't finished golfing. Should be fixed now.

Comment: @JamesHolderness The question was changed since I submitted my answer, I'd have to update it.

Comment: @JamesHolderness Yep. Sorry about that, Neil. I just needed to clarify some parts of the question that I didn't clarify earlier.

Comment: @JamesHolderness I realise that, which is why I have marked my answer as noncompeting as it answered a previous iteration of the question, until such time as I am able to update it to the current requirements.

Comment: @JamesHolderness OK I think this version works now.

Answer (score 3):

### Python 2, <s>244</s> 241 bytes

```python
m=[]
for l in input():
 for i in range(len(l)):
  c=l[i];a=i/2+1;L,R=[a,a+1,'LR'[c>'v']],[a,a+1,'RL'[c>'v']];x=m.index(L)if L in m else-1;M=zip(*m[:x+1])
  if c in'xX':
   if x>=0and(a in M[1]or a+1in M[0])<1:del m[x]
   else:m=[R]+m
print m
```

Takes input as list of strings

**Example:**

Input: `['| | | |', ' X  | |', '| |  x ', '|  X  |', ' x  | |']`

Output: `[[1, 2, 'L'], [2, 3, 'R'], [3, 4, 'L'], [1, 2, 'R']]`

Edit:
Fixed for case:

Input: `['| | |', ' X  |', ' X  |', ' x  |', '|  X', ' X  |', ' x  |', ' x  |', '| | |']`

Output: `[[1, 2, 'L'], [2, 3, 'R'], [1, 2, 'R']]`

Comment: @JamesHolderness Should be fixed now.

Comment: This looks like it's working properly now!

Comment: @JamesHolderness Yes, that seems like a problem. Please fix that, TFeld. Otherwise, nice attempt!

Comment: @AlexL. Should be fixed now